# Itertools cycle method — why the "while" loop?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Reviewing the implementation details of itertools.cycle, it seemed to me that the while loop was used to reset the generator (function with a yield) and provide an infinite repeat of an iterable, but if that were the case, while not move up the while up and delete the second half of the method. Assuming that they are smarter than I am, I am assuming that I am missing something, though the second function below seems to work with yielded dicts and lists and strings.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

vs.

```
def cycle_huh(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    while True:
        for element in iterable:
            yield element
```

I must be missing something? Or an iterable type where the first is required and the second would break it.

Comment: Some iterators can be exhausted. That means they will be empty after the first iteration. That's why cycle has to collect all the items in the initial run.

Comment: Generators can only be iterated once. So you need to save them to a list to repeat them. Try this with your `cycle` and see what happens: `with open("textfile.txt") as f: for line in cycle(f): print(line)`

Comment: Thanks, Good point. When done with itertools.chain, works as expected. And if the file is large, oops! Mine, it loops once and hangs. Must be in the empty white loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `iterable` is a generator or other proper iterator (rather than, say, a list), then it will be exhausted by the first pass through the `for element in iterable` loop, and subsequent passes through this loop will yield nothing.  You need to save the contents of the iterable somewhere while iterating through the first time in order to avoid this happening.

Comment: OK... so you store the value in a non generator iterable, like a list? Got it... duh.. Must be Sunday night. Should have done one more test instead of thinking it through... (built in delay before accepting answer... shortly)

Comment: "or other proper iterable" <- I think you meant to say iterator.

Comment: You mean proper *iterator*. Lists are proper iterables, but not iterators at all.

Comment: It's an important distinction and one that probably led to the above question. Yes. Thank you.  All.